# Inheritance static variable member, but share it separately to every kind of the inheritance class

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-members

If class inherits base class with static variable member, Will be their only one member that shared with all classes that inheritances.

I have few kinds inherits classes, and many instance of every one of them. 
I want that every one of the inherits classes will have a separate static member, that shared with all of its instances.

How can it be done?

thank you, and sorry about my poor English.

edit:

```
class a{
static int var;};
class b::a{};
class c::a{};
```

Now, I want that all instances of b will have same *var*, and all instances of c will have same *var*  , but the *var* of b will be different from the *var* of c.

I'm sorry again about my English, if you can correct me, please do it.

Comment: Separate static member that shared with all of its instances. You are contradicting yourself.

Comment: Check @BatchyX's answer. It's dead on :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can work aroud that using CRTP :

```
struct YourBaseBaseClass {
    // put everything that does not depend on your static variable
};

template <YourSubclass>
struct YourBaseClass : YourBaseBaseClass {
    static Member variable;
    // and everything that depend on that static variable.
};

struct AClass : YourBaseClass<AClass> {
     // there is a "variable" static variable here
};

struct AnotherClass : YourBaseClass<AnotherClass> {
     // which is different from the "variable" static variable here.
};
```

`AClass` and `AnotherClass` both have a `variable` static variable (of type `Member`), but the first one is a static variable from `YourBaseClass<AClass>` and the other is from `YourBaseClass<AnotherClass>`, which are two different classes.

`YourBaseBaseClass` is optional, but you need it if you want to manipulate `AClass` and `AnotherClass` using a `YourBaseBaseClass*` pointer (you cannot have a `YourBaseClass*` pointer, because `YourBaseClass` is not a class).

And remember to define those static variables.

Comment: +1, but common practice is to use classes instead of structs, whenever you have inheritance or methods involved. Adding in a (empty?) virtual destructor to YourBaseBaseClass also is important.

Comment: Very nice. thanks BatchyX. I'm still hope that there is more simplest solution.

Comment: @smerlin: Yeah, and i should put that in a header, and i should define the static variables, and i should put real code instead of comments, and i should document those classes, and i should typedef supers, and i should write test cases, and i should ...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put the static member in the base class in this scenario. But you can try to put it in the derived class and access it by calling an static method in the base class. So instances of Derived and Derived2 can share different static members. And you force the derived class to define a static member named value if its GetStaticValue() method is called.

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:

    static int GetStaticValue()
    {
        return T::value;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    friend class Base<Derived>;
private:
    static int value;
};

int Derived::value = 1;

class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2>
{
    friend class Base<Derived2>;
private:
    static int value;
};

int Derived2::value = 2;

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Derived da;
    int ret = d.GetStaticValue();
    ret = da.GetStaticValue();
    // As everything is static you don't need to instantiate the Derived classes
    ret = Base<Derived>::GetStaticValue(); 

    Derived2 d2;
    Derived2 d2a;
    ret = d2.GetStaticValue();
    ret = d2a.GetStaticValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Static members are different from non-static members. Static members are called class variables, while non-static members are called instance variables. This is because non-static members belong to a particular object (instance of a class), while static variables are shared.

Thus, static members do not follow the same rules of inheritance, and remain property of the class that defines them.

Comment: So i guess I should add that if A is base and B is derived, u can access the static member from B method by "A::member"

Comment: @user983064 This wasn't my question. Please see my edit, maybe now it's more clearly.